# What does the 'h' suffix mean?

Tags: assembly, x86

In x86 assembly, what does an `h` suffix on numbers represent?

For example:

```
sub CX, 13h
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

"H" for "Hexadecimal", base 16.  0009H = 9 decimal, 000AH = 10 decimal, 000FH = 15 decimal, 0010H = 16, 0020H = 32 et cetera.