# Why "segment register's value must first be multiplied by 16"?

Tags: assembly

Recently I have read a book, it mentioned that "the segment register's value must first be multiplied by 16".

For example, `MOV AL, [ES:BX]` means **move contents of ES*16+BX to register AL**. And I have searched some articals on the web mentioned things like this, too:

1. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-the-stack-segment-and-the-extra-segment-in-8086#
2. [Physical address calculation assembly IAPX8088](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145039/physical-address-calculation-assembly-iapx8088/32145320#32145320)

I just wondering why 16 here? What does 16 mean?

Update:

1. I mean, if I want to access address 16, `MOV BX, 16` and `MOV ES, 1` works all the same? It is weird for me. I thought ES is the leftmost bit, if ES is 1, so the address is `ES*65536+BX`...

Comment: Why 16? Because that's how the chip was designed.

Comment: So it's just a formula I don't need to no why?  Just remember it is OK?

Comment: The chip designers decided to organize their chip that way. Not sure what sort of a "why" answer you are looking for. "Why does the library put the music CDs on the west wall?" Um, because that's where they put them. Doesn't really matter why they are on the west wall. If you are looking for music CDs, you should look on the west wall because that's where they are.

Comment: I don't know why not `ES*65536+BX` here.

Comment: A 20-bit address bus was the design goal.  Packaging no doubt played a major role, they didn't dare making a chip with more than 40 pins.  One megabyte was *huge* back then, it did last for more than 15 years.

Comment: ES*65536+BX would be wasteful of memory because it means that segments were a full 64KB, even if you needed only 2048 bytes.

Comment: @HansPassant: It's not obvious why they didn't make the segment shift 8 (`ES*256 + BX`), but still only build a chip with 20-bit physical addressing.  That would mean the top 4 bits of segment registers would be ignored (or have to be all zero) in the initial model of the CPU, but would give it room to grow by a factor of 16.  Did being able to overlap segments with such fine-grained control really help?  Or was it more a matter of not wanting to design a chip with larger logical address-space than was physically supported?

Comment: Overlap is useful to address more than 64KB of data ("huge" pointers).  The smaller the multiplier, the less address space is wasted on the segment size granularity and the more memory you can address with a huge pointer.  So it is exactly as large as it needs to be to get a 1 MB address space.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the day of segmented memory and 16 bit address space it allowed you to address a whole 1 MB of memory, which was what the original 8086 supported (it had a 20 bit external address bus), still keeping both "near" pointers and segment registers 16 bit wide.

```
 ssssssssssssssss0000 +    segment (16 bit) * 16 (= left shift 4)
 0000pppppppppppppppp =    near pointer (16 bit)
------------------------
xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      physical address (20 bit + something)
```

(you can actually go almost 64 KB beyond 1 MB, which originally resulted in wraparound and then resulted in the whole A20 issue)

Comment: Did being able to overlap segments with such fine-grained control really help?  Or was it more a matter of not wanting to design a chip with larger logical address-space than was physically supported?  A segment shift of 8 would seem natural, and leave a factor of 16 more room for future expansion.  (The upper 4 bits of a segment register would be ignored on CPUs with only 20 bit physical addresses, or required to be all-zero, but that's fine.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: sorry, I don't really have an answer to this - but it's an interesting question that I'd be happy to see answered. When I initially replied the question seemed to me more about "what purpose has multiplying by 16" not "why *exactly* 16". (actually, I'm thinking about deleting this answer, as I don't have the knowledge to give a precise answer to this exact decision)

Comment: It's a good answer to the basic part of the question the OP had, which included *What does 16 mean?*, and perhaps "what's the point of segmentation in the first place".  A good way to expand this answer would be to address what RaymondChen pointed out in comments: overlapping segments are useful if you don't need a separate 64k for each one, but don't want to just use a Tiny code model with all of them having the same base.  (That answers the "why not 65536" part)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think a shift of 8 could've worked, especially since segments less than 64K in size can potentially overlap the previous segment without wasting space on padding up to 256 byte boundaries. But I think it comes down to the Intel engineers thinking about it the other way around. They had decided on 16-bit segment registers and 20 address lines and since 20 - 16 = 4, that's what the segment shift should be. If they had felt they could only cram 19 address lines in there then the shift probably would've been 3.

Answer (score -1):

The process of getting a memory address is:  
 
base memory register*16 + relative memory register.

Example:
 **[ds:si]** 
 
Assuming *DS* stores the value 700h and *SI* stores the value 7h the instruction will act as:  
 
**[700h:7h]**  
 
and this will dereference the memory of 7007h  (700h*16+7h = 7007h).

Therefore [700h:7h] is same as [7007h].

Why 16?, hexadecimal number multiplying by 16 will be same as pushing the number left so: 
 **700h*16=7000h**

Comment: Yo what? 700h:7h is 700h*10h+7h (or 700h<<4+7h) which is 7007h

Comment: Your answer is still wrong, even after the edit! __7010h (700h*16h+7h = 7010h).__

Comment: @Fifoernik 'h' suffix indicates the value as hexadecimal value, which means that 16h means 22 as decimal, therefore 700h*16h+7h != 7010h . this is the reason you are wrong.

Comment: What? The text in boldface is exactly what __YOU__ wrote as an answer. Rest assured that I know my hexadecimals. Don't try to be smart with me!

Comment: @Fifoernik [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030959/what-does-the-h-suffix-mean)   I'm not trying "to be smart with you", you claimed that im the one who wrong but there is no point in arguing because 16h it is 22 in decimal representation.

Comment: @Fifoernik hexadecimal numbers should have "h" suffix, decimal numbers require no suffix.

Comment: Why don't you just read what you have written in your actual answer to the original question? Apparently you can accept being told by @MichaelPetch about an error in your answer, but can not see that you need to correct the whole of the answer.

Comment: You still left 2 occurences of the number 7010h to be replaced by 7007h.